# Constrained optimisation to unconstrained using trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have this problem:

$max\{ xy: x^2+y^2 \leq 1,  x,y >0\}$

Solving this gives us $(x,y) = (\frac{\sqrt2}2 , \frac{\sqrt2}2)$

I was wondering if we could make this somehow an unconstrained problem.

My first try was to take $x = a\cos(\theta)$ and $y = b\sin(\theta)$ with $0<a,b \leq 1$ and $ 0 \leq\theta \leq \pi/2$

But then I realised this is also constrained.

Could I have some hint as to how to proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean, unconstrained as in $x,y \in \Bbb R^2$? In that case, there is no maximum as $x,y$ can be arbitrarily large

Comment: the extrema must lie on the curve $$x^2+y^2=1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how do I justify that it is on the curve? withought resorting to optimization methods? If I can justify it is on the curve then I just make x = cos a and y = cos a.

Comment: write $$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$  and you will get the function $$f(x)=x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ and differentiate this with respect to $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$f(x)=x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ then we have
$$f'(x)=-{\frac {2\,{x}^{2}-1}{\sqrt {- \left( x-1 \right)  \left( x+1
 \right) }}}
$$ solving $$f'(x)=0$$ we get $$x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ (note that $$x>0$$ is given!)